# Want to get the database fields used in SAP TCode report

Tags: abap, sap-data-dictionary

I am working on a data governance project with a lot of custom tcodes in SAP environment for various reports. Over a time there has been developed a lot of similar reports with minimal differences.

My requirement is to fetch all the fields used in a tcode report and compare it with other Tcode reports to check how many such redundant reports exist and to what extent.

I am looking for a good idea around this challenge.

Regards
Jnaneswar
University of South Alabama

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a moment and look into this to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How are these reports structured? Just simple selection screen with a `SELECT` from database under the hood?

Comment: The reports are a kind of SELECT from database. They sometimes also include additional summation kind of operations and some columns may involve information from multiple fields

Answer (score 0):

Each report has its application in its metadata (like FI or MM).
I would use this information to structure the problem into parts. I assume that this information is valid most of the times (especially when copied).

You can read the sourcecode with

```
READ REPORT prog INTO itab [MAXIMUM WIDTH INTO wid].
```

and analyze it.

I would search for similarity by the tables used: 
Wherever you find a pattern

```
FROM (tablename)
```

in the source code, group reports by the tables used. This should give you enough ideas which reports are similar.

And only for cases where this is to much (like hundreds of reports selecting from `BKPF`and `BSEG` and `T001`) I would look for ideas fur further structuring. But only *after* running the simple analysis I described and looking at the result.

P.S.:
And I would fix the decission process that lead to thos similar reports.